# Make: missing separator error, despite using tab

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gedit

This is driving me crazy, this is my literal copy-pasted code, Gedit uses a tab-width of 8. It still complains about a missing separator. I followed the manual syntax exactly. I did not use some sort of setting that automatically changes tabs into spaces.

```
Tubes : TubesWithVaryingRadiusAndColors.cxx
    gcc -c TubesWithVaryingRadiusAndColors.cxx
```

In the code above it seems to change the tab in 4 spaces (I can see that by trying to select it, in the typing window it's one character, but if you check it, it'll be 4 spaces).

Edit:

if I use leafpad, it works. What is Gedit doing wrong?

The hexdump is:

```
0000000 494c 4442 5249 3d20 2f20 7375 2f72 696c
0000010 2f62 7476 2d6b 2e35 2f38 540a 6275 7365
0000020 3a20 5420 6275 7365 6957 6874 6156 7972
0000030 6e69 5267 6461 7569 4173 646e 6f43 6f6c
0000040 7372 632e 7878 090a 6367 2063 632d 5420
0000050 6275 7365 6957 6874 6156 7972 6e69 5267
0000060 6461 7569 4173 646e 6f43 6f6c 7372 632e
0000070 7878 2d20 2049 7b24 494c 4442 5249 007d
000007f
```

Comment: Works fine for me. That null character at the end is a bit odd, though as I said, works fine for me (`make: *** No rule to make target 'TubesWithVaryingRadiusAndColors.cxx', needed by 'Tubes'.  Stop.`).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `hexdump` on your `Makefile`. You'll then be absolutely certain of how actually the tab is coded.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `gedit`'s Editor preferences i.e. `Edit->Preferences->Editor`, uncheck `Insert spaces instead of tabs`.

Try inserting the tab character again in the `Makefile`, and this time it should work.

BTW, a tab width of 8 spaces is not equivalent to a `hard-tab`. `Gedit` seems to be automatically replacing the tab character with `8 spaces` but `Makefile` expects the tab character to be present at the beginning of every `recipe` for a rule.

If you were using an editor like `vim` it would automatically take care to insert hard-tabs for specifying rules, and you could manually insert a tab using <kbd>Ctrl-V-Tab</kbd>

Comment: Like I said, it really is a tab, I don't know what kind. "Insert spaces instead of tabs" was already unchecked. Also which vim do I use? I tried vim-athena and vim and I still can't find the program.

Comment: @PatronBernard,can you post the output of `od -t a Makefile`, since it would be much easier to interpret ? BTW, your hexdump did not match the hex dump I see for almost the same content in the Makefile, for some reason, may be the character-set is different ?

Comment: I guess so, it's weird that Gedit would do such a thing. I never even touched/modified it. Very frustrating. I'm just gonna switch to Vim I think.

Comment: `vim` can do the same if the `expandtab` option is set. So do not forget to set `noexpandtab` for make files.